# When are MYSQL delimiters useful?

Tags: mysql

I am writing SQL to create a trigger for a table in my database. This code should be in a script we can run whenever we spawn a new database.

I have been reading the SQL doc to understand how to do this and eventually came up with a query of this type:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER calendar_event_after_insert AFTER INSERT 
ON calendar_event
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF @log_calendar_event_id = 'YES'
  THEN
    ...
  END IF;
  IF @log_calendar_event_name = 'YES'
  THEN
    ...
  END IF;
  ...
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I am getting an error on my use of DELIMITER, and I admit I don't understand much of how that works. My basic understanding is that since there are multiple queries inside this big one that all end with a `;` I need to tell sql when this query ends using another delimiter.

After reading a bit about delimiters this seems like the right syntax to me, and on top of that i have been running this query in sequel pro and it works at times and at times it does not (weird, I know).

So eventually I decided to remove the delimiters part and everything works smoothly. I am a bit worried this will have side effects tho.

So my question is: when are delimiters used? are they useful in my case? if so, what am I doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT as requested in comments**

This is the error I get when running the query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER calendar_event_after_insert AFTER
>   INSERT ON calenda' at line 1

FYI we have an old version of MYSQL installed on our dev machines -- MYSQL 5.1.73

Comment: "Delimiter" refers to the "end of statement" indicator used by the interactive shell. The server uses `;` to delimit statements inside of stored procedures. What you have here should work, so if you get an error please edit your question and post the exact text you received back from the server.

Comment: I am not familiar with "sequel pro"; but if you're using some kind of "create procedure" feature, it could be already wrapping it with DELIMITER calls behind the scenes for you. Have you tried running your version with DELIMITER in something more general, like a query tab in MySQL Workbench? _I've used some software that provided "breakpoints" for debugging in stored procedures by basically inserting a bunch of it's own sql  into the procedure code it was provided; that could cause similar hard to find issues at times._

Comment: You only need `DELIMITER` if you're running the query in the `mysql` console. If it's being passed as a query directly, then you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @Uueerdo I get the same error even when I run it in PHP.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that's good to know! Do you have any source for that? Is it because a language module already tells mysql when the query ends?

Comment: @NicolaPedretti is that error from running it in a simple php query interface, or a table management "add trigger" one?

Comment: About [halfway down](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) the manual page for triggers.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol ! Do you mind creating and answer exaplinging it is only useful for the mysql client and quoting your source? I can do it too if you don't want to but I wouldn't want to take the credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELIMITER` is not part of the SQL language. It's a [command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html) of the [official command-line tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html):

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command.

There're some third-party programs that also implement a `delimiter` command in order to be able to run complex MySQL scripts (e.g. HeidiSQL).

If you are running your script in a context that doesn't allow multiple statements (e.g. a typical PHP application) the command will neither exist nor be needed at all.